# c# Background worker class

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to put this method into background worker class, i am trying but stuck, 
can any one help me how to run this method into background worker class:
I am calling this method into my asp.net page, where file are zipped on server and then returend to the client. but zipping of file may take longer and user will see a busy screen, so to avoid that i want to use background worker class:

```
[Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
public string Zip(string f, bool original)
{
    string zip = "";
    try
    {
        files = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(files);
        string[] fileCollection = files.Split('*');
        zipFile = class1.zipfile(fileCollection, IsOriginal);

        int fileLength = files.Length;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception during processing {0}", ex);
   }
    return File;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? how far have you got? [MSDN has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) of using `BackgroundWorker` - it should be simply a case of putting your code in place of theirs. Also, note that background worker is *more commonly* used to avoid blocking a UI - sure, you can *use* it from a console, but that is less common. In many ways, I might just use `ThreadPool` here...

Comment: Your method does not give much sense. First off, `zip` is never used. And you are returning `File` that does not exist anywhere.

Comment: @ marc Gravell: I am confused by how to pass arguments to the methods and also this method is returning a value so i am confuse with it,

Comment: wait... are you trying to use if from a *web* app? It is very unclear what your entire cycle is here, but that seems.... odd.

Comment: @: Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen: I want to put this method into a background worker class, as this method is used for zipping files on server and it takes longs. I am calling this method in asp.net page.

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: yes i am using it in a web application, i.e asp.net, the method is called for zipping files and it may take longer depending on size of file being zipped.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to use a `BackgroundWorker` in a web app? Who told you to do that?

Comment: @ Cody Gray: well if i shouldnt do this, then the user will see a busy web page until the zipping of file are completed. in this case i find it the best, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Is a progress bar in a client's browser during the compression what you are after? If it is so you need to create a reporting mechanism that will answer to ajax calls from the client. Of course, the compression method must be able to compress the files in chunks or be able to somehow report progress.

Comment: @ jaroslav jandek: I am using Ajax, and on the client, if the file size is like 500 MB then compression on sever take long, and the page for the user is busy. so to run this zipping in background on server, while the user continue to browse on the page and when zipping is completed, the file start downloading.

Comment: @Safi, what you should do is this: 1. Start an external process (another application you've written) that does the zipping. Do this in a fire and forget style (that is don't wait (from your ASP.NET app) for the process to finish). If there are errors, let this other app log them. 2. If you're familiar with MSQM then use MSMQ for this. Once again, the idea is to kick off a process (out of band process) and return immediately (in your ASP.NET) application.

Comment: @ Shiv Kumar, thanks for the suggestion so you think fire and forget or MSQM Will help me and i odnt need to use Background Worker Class? PLUS what is the best way of putting fire and forget or MSQM in this scenirio?

Comment: @safi, read your answer to @jaroslav. If the client has to wait till the process is complete so the file starts to download after then there is no much you can do. Of course you can do what I said earlier and from the browser (using AJAX) you can poll the server every 15-20 seconds to see if the zipping is done. If it is, the server side could respond with a url to the zip file and the ajax call can direct the page to the url, effectively starting the download of the file. But the user will still have to wait on that page (unless you do something fanzy with hidden iframes).

Comment: @ Shiv Kumar: I dont understand with IFRAMES?

Comment: If you're not very familiar with MSMQ, I suggest using a console app to do the zipping. Your ASP.NET app can trigger the process using System.Diagnostics.Process, passing any command line parameters to the console app. When you start a process using the "Process" class you have the option to wait till the process finishes or not. So don't. If the client must wait then you don't have much of a choice. See my previous comment for some other options.

Comment: @safi, don't worry about (or go down the route of) iframes. It could land you with a brittle solution rather than a robust one.

Comment: Personally I think you are looking at the wrong options; you would do better to start again in a new question with *what you want to achieve*, rather than *how you are currently doing it*, since BackgroundWorker is just not the right option here. This is something that is too big to do in combination with any single request - I suspect you will need to do this entirely out of band (perhaps a long-running thread, or perhaps shell an exe), and update something in the user's state that *later* (when they subsequently make a request) advertises a URL that they might use, or sends them an e-mail.

Comment: @ thanks for your reply, well sending them and email isnt an option here as the client do not want his inbox with these images. Secondly what is the option then you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your problem is returning the value from the BackgroundWorker. That can be done like this:

In the worker's DoWork method, set the `e.Result` to what you want to return:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    ...
    e.Result = File;
}
```

Then, in the `RunWorkerCompleted` method, you can access this value in the main thread:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = e.Result as string;
}
```

I have assumed that `File` is string here, but you can cast it to your required object.

Why you need it in a web application I have no clue, but this is how to do it at least ;)

Comment: Thanks, I need in the web APP because I am calling this method into my asp.net page, where file are zipped on server and then returend to the client. but zipping of file may take longer if file size is e.g. 500 mb and user will see a busy page until the processing of zipping is completed and the chrome/mozilla recognize as a suspecisous script running so ask the user to kill the page :(

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this using AJAX to keep the client responsive, while the server is working. The A in AJAX stands for  Asynchronous for a reason ;)

Comment: @ I m already using ajax on this method: like 
    [Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]